# taint-mode perl: preserve suid when running external program via system()

Tags: perl, bash, taint, suexec, suid

I'm trying to add a feature to a legacy script. The script is suid, and uses perl -T (taint mode: man perlsec), for extra security. The feature I need to add is implemented in Python.

The problem is that I can't convince perlsec to preserve the suid permissions, no matter how much I launder the environment and my command lines.

This is frustrating, since it preserves the suid for other binaries (such as /bin/id). Is there an undocumented special case for /usr/bin/perl? This seems unlikely.

Does anyone know a way to make this work? (**As-is**: We don't have the resources to re-architect this whole thing.)

---

**Solution:** (as per @gbacon)

```
# use the -p option to bash
system('/bin/bash', '-p', '-c', '/usr/bin/id -un');

# or set real user and group ids
$< = $>;
$( = $);
system('/usr/bin/python', '-c', 'import os; os.system("/usr/bin/id -un")');
```

This gives the desired results!

---

Here's a cut-down version of my script, which still shows my problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
## This is an SUID script: man perlsec
%ENV = ( "PATH" => "" );

##### PERLSEC HELPERS #####
sub tainted (@) {
    # Prevent errors, stringifying
    local(@_, $@, $^W) = @_;  

    #let eval catch the DIE signal
    $SIG{__DIE__}  = '';      
    my $retval = not eval { join("",@_), kill 0; 1 };
    $SIG{__DIE__}  = 'myexit';      

    return $retval
}

sub show_taint {
    foreach (@_) {
        my $arg = $_; #prevent "read-only variable" nonsense
        chomp $arg;
        if ( tainted($arg) ) {
            print "TAINT:'$arg'";
        } else {
            print "ok:'$arg'";
        }
        print ", ";
    }
    print "\n";
}

### END PERLSEC HELPERS ###

# Are we SUID ? man perlsec
my $uid = `/usr/bin/id --user` ;
chomp $uid;

my $reluser = "dt-pdrel";
my $reluid = `/usr/bin/id --user $reluser 2> /dev/null`;
chomp $reluid;

if ( $uid ne $reluid ) {
    # what ? we are not anymore SUID ? somebody must do a chmod u+s $current_script
    print STDERR "chmod 4555 $myname\n";
    exit(14);
}

# comment this line if you don't want to autoflush after every print
$| = 1;


# now, we're safe, single & SUID
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# BEGIN of main code itself


print "\nENVIRON UNDER BASH:\n";
run('/bin/bash', '-c', '/bin/env');

print "\nTAINT DEMO:\n";
print "\@ARGV: ";
show_taint(@ARGV);
print "\%ENV: ";
show_taint(values %ENV);
print "`cat`: ";
show_taint(`/bin/cat /etc/host.conf`);

print "\nworks:\n";
run('/usr/bin/id', '-un');
run('/usr/bin/id -un');

print "\ndoesn't work:\n";
run('/bin/bash', '-c', '/usr/bin/id -un');
run('/bin/bash', '-c', '/bin/date >> /home/dt-pdrel/date');
run('/bin/date >> /home/dt-pdrel/date');
run('/usr/bin/python', '-c', 'import os; os.system("/usr/bin/id -un")');
run('/usr/bin/python', '-c', 'import os; os.system("/usr/bin/id -un")');


sub run {
    my @cmd = @_;
    print "\tCMD: '@cmd'\n";
    print "\tSEC: ";
    show_taint(@cmd);
    print "\tOUT: ";
    system @cmd ;
    print "\n";
}
```

And here's the output:

```
$ id -un
bukzor

$ ls -l /proj/test/test.pl
-rwsr-xr-x 1 testrel asic 1976 Jul 22 14:34 /proj/test/test.pl*

$ /proj/test/test.pl foo bar

ENVIRON UNDER BASH:
        CMD: '/bin/bash -c /bin/env'
        SEC: ok:'/bin/bash', ok:'-c', ok:'/bin/env', 
        OUT: PATH=
PWD=/proj/test2/bukzor/test_dir/
SHLVL=1
_=/bin/env


TAINT DEMO:
@ARGV: TAINT:'foo', TAINT:'bar', 
%ENV: ok:'', 
`cat`: TAINT:'order hosts,bind', 

works:
        CMD: '/usr/bin/id -un'
        SEC: ok:'/usr/bin/id', ok:'-un', 
        OUT: testrel

        CMD: '/usr/bin/id -un'
        SEC: ok:'/usr/bin/id -un', 
        OUT: testrel


doesn't work:
        CMD: '/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/id -un'
        SEC: ok:'/bin/bash', ok:'-c', ok:'/usr/bin/id -un', 
        OUT: bukzor

        CMD: '/bin/bash -c /bin/date >> /home/testrel/date'
        SEC: ok:'/bin/bash', ok:'-c', ok:'/bin/date >> /home/testrel/date', 
        OUT: /bin/bash: /home/testrel/date: Permission denied

        CMD: '/bin/date >> /home/testrel/date'
        SEC: ok:'/bin/date >> /home/testrel/date', 
        OUT: sh: /home/testrel/date: Permission denied

        CMD: '/usr/bin/python -c import os; os.system("/usr/bin/id -un")'
        SEC: ok:'/usr/bin/python', ok:'-c', ok:'import os; os.system("/usr/bin/id -un")', 
        OUT: bukzor

        CMD: '/usr/bin/python -c import os; os.system("/usr/bin/id -un")'
        SEC: ok:'/usr/bin/python', ok:'-c', ok:'import os; os.system("/usr/bin/id -un")', 
        OUT: bukzor
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your real userid to the effective (suid-ed) one. You probably want to do the same for your real group id:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -T

use warnings;
use strict;

$ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin";

system "id -un";
system "/bin/bash", "-c", "id -un";

# set real user and group ids
$< = $>;
$( = $);

system "/bin/bash", "-c", "id -un";
```

Sample run:

```
$ ls -l suid.pl
-rwsr-sr-x 1 nobody nogroup 177 2010-07-22 20:33 suid.pl

$ ./suid.pl 
nobody
gbacon
nobody
```

What you're seeing is documented `bash` behavior:

> #### `-p`
>
> Turn on privileged mode. In this mode, the `$BASH_ENV` and `$ENV` files are not processed, shell functions are not inherited from the environment, and the `SHELLOPTS`, `BASHOPTS`, `CDPATH` and `GLOBIGNORE` variables, if they appear in the environment, are ignored. If the shell is started with the effective user (group) id not equal to the real user (group) id, and the `-p` option is not supplied, these actions are taken and the effective user id is set to the real user id. If the `-p` option is supplied at startup, the effective user id is not reset. Turning this option off causes the effective user and group ids to be set to the real user and group ids.

This means you could also

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -T

use warnings;
use strict;

$ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin";

system "/bin/bash", "-p", "-c", "id -un";
```

to get

```
nobody
```

Recall that passing multiple arguments to `system` bypasses the shell. A single argument does go to the shell, but probably not `bash`—look at the output of `perl -MConfig -le 'print $Config{sh}'`.

Maybe consider using `use English '-no_match_vars';` for mental sanity:
It will provide `$GID`, `$EGID`, `$UID`, `$EUID`, etc.

Comment: @bukzor I'm glad my explanation helped!

Comment: perl uses /bin/sh when it needs a shell, but on my system and most linux systems, this is a symlink to /bin/bash. The functionality is slightly different when invoked as sh, but it still accepts the -p option.